# setCompoundDrawablePadding() to zero

Tags: android

i want to Put the image on text in the button.
I want to set the spacing between text and images to zero.

In addition, a button with a size of 200 dp x 200 dp
I want the images and text to be laid out in the same vertical padding.
Please help me.

```
    Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,getTheme());

    b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,d,null,null);
    b.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0);
    b.setText("good");
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hellow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative way of doing this and it can prove easier.
Instead of using a `Button` and trying to use an drawable with it, have you considered using a `TextView` and add a drawable to it? It can be done within your XML and you can add padding. Something like,

```
<TextView
          android:id="@+id/my_textview"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
          android:textColor="@color/text_secondary_dark"
          android:drawablePadding="8dp"
          android:drawableTop="@drawable/my_icon"
          tools:drawableTint="#000"/>
```

As you can see, you can add a drawable, its padding, its tint etc.